# GCHQ's code-breaker challenge?

Tags: cipher

BBC Radio 4 has just released a [code breaker challenge](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/5m5cv4NM5dWx108YgCQXj9J/can-you-crack-gchqs-code-breaker-challenge?intc_type=promo&intc_location=sport&intc_campaign=codebreakerchallenge&intc_linkname=radio4_ent_quiz1) and I am totally stuck.

> If Samuel transcribed what Louis wrote…
>   …and Louis wrote what Ludwik translated…
>   …and Ludwik translated what Tim said…
>   …then what did Tim say?
>
> Here is Samuel’s transcription:
>   
>   `IN AAAAIAN INAAANAIA IA IAINA AI AA IAIIA IAA AAIAAINN AA IAAANN IAINANI
>   NA ANNNNMA NAANIANMN NN ANNAN NN AM MNNNN ANI MAAINNIA AM NNAMIA NNAANIN
>   AM MMIAAMA MMIMAAMMA MM AMAAA MA AM AAAMA AAA MAMAAAAM AM AAIMMM MMMMAMA`
>
> CLUE: The key to unlocking the puzzle is identifying Samuel, Louis and Ludwik. There are links between them!

For those of you wanting to try it out here is the [PDF version](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/radio4/GCHQ_Codebreaker_Challenge.pdf).

The answer will be revealed on 22/11/2016 but hopefully we will have an answer by then.

Comment: [Samuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Morse) and [Louis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Daguerre), probably.

Comment: Off topic because on going competition?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Is it a competition though, or just an ongoing *challenge*?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 there isn't a prize to be won, its just for fun.

Comment: @randal'thor Thanks for the steer :)

Comment: @randal'thor Why that Louis? It's got to be the one Levieux guesses.

Comment: @Gareth Yes, Levieux's guess is better. I found that Louis by looking for people called Louis who were linked to that Samuel, since the question says "there are links between them".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The obvious thing to do (I agree with Levieux) is to reverse the process from

> Morse (`.`=dot, `-`=blank) to Braille to Esperanto to, I suppose, English.

In case there's any doubt about Louis, note that

> the message is of three lines, all with the same pattern of letters and spaces; and the four letters used are exactly the ones made up of two Morse code elements.

The message appears to be

> ni bezonas diverseco de penso en la mondo por alfronti la novaji defiojn

which seems to mean

> we need diversity of thought in the world to face the new challenges

which is a quotation from

> Tim Berners-Lee

although Google Translate doesn't like the penultimate word in the translated version; maybe I have made a transcription error.

Comment: Wow, that's fast. I was just half way.

Comment: Well done, that looks correct. Still working on the first section myself haha.

Comment: My process, since two people have now remarked I was faster than them: (1) copy the text into a text editor (I use Vim). (2) Use global replace to turn `A` into `.-_` etc. (3) Use global replace to turn spaces into multiple spaces and `_` into single spaces, so now I can see the characters. (4) Pull up a chart of the Braille alphabet and translate letter by letter. I don't think there's anything super-smart there. I'm quick at looking things up in charts, good at remembering things I've seen before, and good at guessing what letter might come next in a Latinate language :-).

Comment: ... and you're obviously good with a text editor. `:)`

Comment: If you're good with vim, there's an absolutely silly amount of power at your fingertips.  I do my solve notes in vim also, for similar reasons.  (This is not an invitation for an editor holy war.  Emacs aficionados, I am not baiting you.)

Comment: Emacs is even more powerful, but I switched to vim when I had wrist trouble. All that Escape Meta Alt Control Shift is bad for the tendons.

Comment: The esperanto word that caused a problem in Google translate was novajn not novaji.

Answer (score 8):

Hmm, I'm thinking

> Ludwik Lejzer Zamenhof translated the message into Esperanto

then

> Louis Braille wrote it down (in Braille)

and finally

> Samuel Morse transcribed it to morse code

Next step is to reverse these steps back into Tim's original message..

First step is to

> convert the letters back into morse with
> A = .-
> N = -.
> I = ..
> M = --
> And then interpret the result as braille probably

Comment: This may be a daft question however how would morse code work on this text where four characters are used?

Comment: I = .. ; M = -- ; N = -. ; A = .-